# (Lazy) Eager Loading does not work with a Custom Collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

### Needs

1. I need to have a CustomCollection
2. I need to use lazy eager loading

### Circumstances & Problem

When I try to lazy eager load by using this construct `$posts->load('author')`, using a custom collection object, I get the error saying that the collection object does not have the method `load`.

### Code

**Post Model:**

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    public function  newCollection(array $models = array())
    {
         return new CustomCollection( $models );
    }
}
```

**CustomCollection**

```
class CustomCollection extends Illuminate\Support\Collection
{

    public function specialCollectionMethod()
    {
         return 'something that a standard collection does not provide';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### I found my mistake!

I realized what I was doing wrong but already wrote the post (above) so I thought I'd fix my mistake:

I realized I need to extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` rather than `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` in my CustomCollection. I misread [the documentation](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html).

### Code

**CustomCollection**

```
class CustomCollection extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
{

    public function specialCollectionMethod()
    {
         return 'something that a standard collection does not provide';
    }
}
```

### Documentation

[image: Laravel Collection Documentation]

Comment: [You may like this](http://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object), article about extending the `Collection` object.